# How to split long list of equations into 2 columns in a document

Tags: latex, overleaf

Good day.
I have this list of equations on a latex document. I intend to split it into two columns to economize space. Here is the code I used:

```
\begin{multicol}{2}
\textit{Chemical Initiation Reaction:}
\begin{equation*}
I\xrightarrow{K_{d}}2fR^{^{\bullet}}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
R^{^{\bullet}}+M\xrightarrow{K_{i}}R_{1}^{^{\bullet}}
\end{equation*}

\textit{Thermal Initiation Reaction:}

\begin{equation*}
3M\xrightarrow{K_{iterm}}M_{1}^{^{\bullet}}+M_{2}^{^{\bullet}}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
M_{1}^{^{\bullet}}+M\xrightarrow{4K_{P}}P_{2}^{^{\bullet}}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
M_{2}^{^{\bullet}}+M\xrightarrow{4K_{P}}P_{3}^{^{\bullet}}
\end{equation*}

\textit{Chain Propagation Reaction:}

\begin{equation*}
P_{n}^{^{\bullet}}+M\xrightarrow{K_{P}}P_{n+1}^{^{\bullet}}
\end{equation*}

\textit{Chain Transfer to Monomer Reaction:}

\begin{equation*}
P_{n}^{^{\bullet}}+M\xrightarrow{K_{trM}}P_{1}^{^{\bullet}}+ D_{n}
\end{equation*}

\textit{Chain Transfer to Solvent Reaction:}

\begin{equation*}
P_{n}^{^{\bullet}}+S\xrightarrow{K_{trS}}P_{1}^{^{\bullet}}+D_{n}
\end{equation*}

\textit{Chain Termination by Combination Reaction :}

\begin{equation*}
P_{n}^{^{\bullet}}+P_{m}^{^{\bullet}}\xrightarrow{K_{tc}}D_{n+m}
\end{equation*}

\textit{Chain Termination by Disproportionation Reaction :}

\begin{equation*}
P_{n}^{^{\bullet}}+P_{m}^{^{\bullet}}\xrightarrow{K_{td}}D_{n}+D_{m}
\end{equation*}
\end{multicol}
```

This is what I am expecting to get below after using the \multicol command.

Comment: Please make a compilable [mre]

Comment: x-post https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/659865/split-long-list-of-equations-into-2-columns-in-a-document/659868#659868

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your use case is but, in the current shape, the equations plus comments are too messy.

It would be better to split equations. Then move comments/annotations to the bottom and then arrange equations in two groups. For annotations, I would make a simple reformatted list with references to equations.

[image]

EDIT (*On adding a caption*)
By default, standard `\caption{...}` would be enough. However, in this particular case, you have to load another package `caption` and use its `\captionof{table}{...}` instead. The former needs to be inside a `table` environment, which is not the case here. So in summy add the following to the code

```
# Somewhere after \documentclass...
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{position=top,skip=12pt}
```

and then right before the `\begin{tabular}...`

```
# Before tabular
\captionof{table}{<Caption of your table>}
```

.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}    % Adds improvements to amsmath
\usepackage{tabularx}     % Groups equations
\usepackage{enumitem}     % To add formatting to standard lists
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{position=top,skip=12pt}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}   % Only for dummy texts


\begin{document}
Start of dummy text. \kant[1][1]

\bigskip

\begingroup
\bgroup
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{-\baselineskip}
\centering
\renewcommand*\tabularxcolumn[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1}
\captionof{table}{Caption of the table below}
\begin{tabularx}{0.85\linewidth}{@{}X|X}
  \textbf{Column 1} & \textbf{Column 2} \\
  \hline
  \begin{gather}
    \begin{gathered}
      I\xrightarrow{K_{d}}2fR^{^{\bullet}} \\
      R^{^{\bullet}}+M\xrightarrow{K_{i}}R_{1}^{^{\bullet}} \\
    \end{gathered} \label{eq:chem-init-react} \\[12pt]
    \begin{gathered}
      3M\xrightarrow{K_{iterm}}M_{1}^{^{\bullet}}+M_{2}^{^{\bullet}} \\
      M_{1}^{^{\bullet}}+M\xrightarrow{4K_{P}}P_{2}^{^{\bullet}} \\
      M_{2}^{^{\bullet}}+M\xrightarrow{4K_{P}}P_{3}^{^{\bullet}}
    \end{gathered} \label{eq:chain-transfer-react}
  \end{gather} &
                 \setlength\jot{6pt}
                 \begin{gather}
                   P_{n}^{^{\bullet}}+M\xrightarrow{K_{P}}P_{n+1}^{^{\bullet}} \label{eq:chain-combine-react} \\
                   P_{n}^{^{\bullet}}+M\xrightarrow{K_{trM}}P_{1}^{^{\bullet}}+ D_{n} \label{eq:thermal-init-react} \\
                   P_{n}^{^{\bullet}}+S\xrightarrow{K_{trS}}P_{1}^{^{\bullet}}+D_{n} \label{eq:chain-propag-react} \\
                   P_{n}^{^{\bullet}}+P_{m}^{^{\bullet}}\xrightarrow{K_{tc}}D_{n+m} \label{eq:chain-transfer-monomer-react} \\
                   P_{n}^{^{\bullet}}+P_{m}^{^{\bullet}}\xrightarrow{K_{td}}D_{n}+D_{m} \label{eq:chain-disprop-react}
                 \end{gather}
\end{tabularx}\par
\egroup
\bigskip

\noindent Annotations:
\begin{itemize}[nosep,before=\vspace{3pt}\itshape]
\item[\eqref{eq:chem-init-react}:] Chemical Initiation Reaction
\item[\eqref{eq:chain-transfer-react}:] Chain Transfer to Solvent Reaction
\item[\eqref{eq:chain-combine-react}:] Chain Termination by Combination Reaction
\item[\eqref{eq:thermal-init-react}:] Thermal Initiation Reaction
\item[\eqref{eq:chain-propag-react}:] Chain Propagation Reaction
\item[\eqref{eq:chain-transfer-monomer-react}:] Chain Transfer to Monomer Reaction
\item[\eqref{eq:chain-disprop-react}:] Chain Termination by Disproportionation Reaction.
\end{itemize}\par
\endgroup

\bigskip

End dummy text. \kant[1][2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you @Celdor. Can you help with adding a caption to the table?

Comment: I updated the code with a few comments. The caption is placed above the table.